# The chosen directory does not exist and attempts to create it failed

Tags: importing-exporting

When I tried to import the data it's showing as "The chosen directory does not exist and attempts to create it failed". What exactly is this I am not getting.

Comment: How do you import it? can you show you code? Keep in mind that you can only do that in the public directory.

Comment: @Namari: whats the difference between public and private directory....

Comment: It needs to go into the sites/default/files directory and not anywhere else. https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/file

Comment: as u said i tried in my localhost its working but when i tried to do same in my company dump it showing error

Comment: do we need to set any permission?

Comment: Is it a read and write directory?  check the permissions that might be the issue. Your webserver need to have read and write access to that directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31990/discussion-between-neethu-and-namari).

Comment: @Namari: yes ur right ,it was permission issue...now i set the right permission, but after importing its creating duplicate data and if i tried to edit the node imported i could not able to edit, alwell the entity reference field are not importing.

Comment: There is a simple solution to this problem. You are just required to make a sub-folder and then retry the backup and it should work. Goodluck!

Comment: Is this import module on Drupal 8? You could undo the last import.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I tried to create a Feed type using Feeds module. I selected the option `upload file` in Fetcher dropdown, and `CSV` in parser. And in Fetcher settings, in the textbox `Upload directory`, I put `public://feeds`.

To solve this error, I created a folder `feeds` in the location `.../web/sites/default/files` and changed the permission of the feeds folder to 777. And when I clicked on Save feed type, I no longer got the error.